# Cloning computer with UEFI boot

Tags: linux, uefi, clone, clonezilla

I have a mini PC where I have installed Arch Linux with UEFI boot.
I'm trying to clone this install on other identical mini PC.
I tried using Clonezilla alternative but at the end of the restoration of the disk image on the cloned computer I have message "EFI boot file in partition /dev/sda1 was *NOT* found." and the new PC won't boot with message "no option to boot to".
Is there a way to create the missing data in the computer BIOS ?
Or are you aware of another tool I can use to clone the computer ?

Answer (score 0):

When using UEFI Bios it's usual to have the EFI configuration files under a different partition. You should clone that aswell. But keep in mind, if you're cloning partitions, disks must be the same size, and you also have to clone the partition table. In your case, I think it's a better option to make an image of the disk. I usually do it with a Debian or Ubuntu bootable usb with [gparted](https://gparted.org/). Good luck.